# Mustache.js - know if a list only has a single item

Tags: javascript, mustache

currently i'm looping through using mustache when i came across the display of authors..

```
{{#authors}}{{.}}, {{/authors}} //loop through each author names in authors array
```

the issue is the comma at the end. i prefer the data (JSON from server) untouched. is there a way in mustache to know if you are in the last iteration (and not append a comma) or know if you are in the first iteration (and not prepend a comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested!

Overview: add a prefix of ", " for all but the first name.

Template:

```
{{#beatles}}
  {{name}}
{{/beatles}}
```

Initialize:

```
window.app.first_flag = true; // initialize
// assumes that the app has created the window.app object/hash to 
// hold the app's data
```

View:

```
 {
  "beatles": [
    { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Lennon" },
    { "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "McCartney" },
    { "firstName": "George", "lastName": "Harrison" },
    { "firstName": "Ringo", "lastName": "Starr" }
  ],
  "name": function () {
     var n = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName,
         prefix = ", ";

     if (window.app.first_flag) {
       window.app.first_flag = false;
       prefix = "";
     }
     return prefix + n; 
  }
}
```

Comment: in my array, i don't have an object but a string. i cannot do `this.firstname` how do i reference them?